# codeigniter model is not loading - 500 internal server error

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a machine on which the model is not loading at all, its 500 internal server error all the time

here is my controller

```
<?php
/*
 *
 * Controller to activate new subscriber with details from partner initiated activation
 *
 */

class PartnerActivation extends CI_Controller
{
    /*
     *
     * Constructor that will call automatically
     *
     * Helper Loading for url and form which is inbuilt feature of code igniter we are using
     *
     *
     */
    public function __construct()

    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper(array('url','form'));   
    }

    public function index()
    {

        if(isset($_POST['invoicedate']))
        {
            $invoicedate = $_POST['invoicedate'];
        }
        else 
        {
            $invoicedate = '';
        }


        if(isset($_POST['deviceid']))
        {
            $deviceid = $_POST['deviceid'];
        }
        else 
        {
            $deviceid = '';
        }

            //save all these fields to a table, and do a http request
            $this->load->model('activation_model','activationmodel',TRUE);
            $this->activationmodel->addPartnerActivation($deviceid,$invoicedate);


    }
}
```

and here is my model - filename is Activation_model.php

```
<?php
class Activation_model extends CI_Model
{


/*
 * partner initiated activation, store this in the database
 */
public function addPartnerActivation($deviceid,$invoicedate)
{
    //never reaches here
        return true;
}

}
```

its grinding my gears

Comment: What does it say in your logs?

Comment: even logs are being made of 0 kb, while i have turned on the logging and even set the environment to "development"

Comment: I'm not familiar with CI. Will things not be written to your normal access and error logs?

Comment: they should, but its just not happening

Comment: Thanks justin, i found a fatal error in logs and fixed it

Comment: @BrijRajSingh you already fixed the code? What was wrong?

Comment: i checked in apache logs, it was due to a semicolon appended at the end of a function in my model, which made that function look like an abstract function without definition, and threw a fatal error

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not reading the logs

Answer (score -3, accepted):

anyways, i fixed it myself, went into apache logs to see what's going on, apparently a function had ';' and then defined, which created a fatal error like this one

[Mon Feb 24 14:04:44 2014] [error] [client 122.176.100.181] PHP Fatal error:  Non-abstract method activation_model::updatePartnerActivation() must contain body in /var/www/api/application/models/activation_model.php on line 157

sorry, and thanks for the help guys, @Justinwood sort of made me tick to check for logs wherever i can

Comment: you can not voted-down due to this reason or without showing link. &  im not copied your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load your models like:

`$this->load->model('Activation_model');` and then call a function like `$this->Activation_model->addPartnerActivation()`. Then it will work..

Comment: nope, didn't worked for me

Comment: Does your code reach till following line: `$this->load->model('activation_model','activationmodel',TRUE);`?

Comment: it reaches and crashes at the load itself

Comment: Can you add a constructor? `function __construct(){ parent::__construct(); }`

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
 $this->load->model('activation_model','activationmodel',TRUE);
 to
 $this->load->model(array('activation_model','activationmodel'));
```

Hope it help

Comment: which is pretty much the same thing here, i have been writing in same syntax since quite some years now

Comment: can u show me a link.@ Brij Raj Singh

Answer (score -1):

In Controller :-

```
        Change :-
            $this->activationmodel->addPartnerActivation($deviceid,$invoicedate);

        To :- 
            $this->activation_model->addPartnerActivation($deviceid,$invoicedate);
```

You are giving a wrong model name while calling the addPartnerActivation .

Hope it's Helps you :)

Comment: don't understand what you are trying to say here

Comment: Please check my answer , i have edited it .
Change the lines that i have mentioned and you are fine

Comment: @SushilSingh That's not true. From CI documentation: **If you would like your model assigned to a different object name you can specify it via the second parameter of the loading function:**

`$this->load->model('Model_name', 'fubar');

$this->fubar->function();`

Comment: Just change "activationmodel" to "activation_model" as i have mentioned .